# IAM Policy Deny AMI Image via Image-Name

Tags: amazon-iam

I can easily deny the deployment of an AWS Image via arn-ami "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-xxx" within an IAM policy but I'm trying to deny all RedHat Images (Marketplace / Community AMIs) deployments

Is this possible via Resource tag and AMI-Name "RHEL-8.2.0_HVM-20200423-x86_64-0-Hourly2-GP2"

Exmaple

````
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "DenyAMIAccess",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-0810abbfb78d37cdf",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-0e2cfc23d72b5cb98",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/name/RHEL*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/RHEL*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Try the below along with "Allow" for Resources "*"

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAMIAccess",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*::image*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "StringNotLike": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Name": "RHEL"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "DenyAMIAccess",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
        "ec2:RunInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:ec2:*::image*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "Null": {
          "aws:RequestTag/Name": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement but in my case I had to deny all CentOS images from being launched. I got it working by creating two custom policies and using two native policies so scoping four policies and worked for me.

I guess in your case you could simply change that from

```
"ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "ec2:Attribute/Condition": [
                        "Linux/Unix",
                        "CentOS*"
```

to:

```
"ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                    "ec2:Attribute/Condition": [
                        "Linux/Unix",
                        "RHEL-*"
```

The first policy below I created denies all CentOS by searching for an attribute that contains any wording that contains centos.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "cloudwatch:*",
            "elasticloadbalancing:*",
            "autoscaling:*"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "iam:AWSServiceName": [
                    "autoscaling.amazonaws.com",
                    "ec2scheduled.amazonaws.com",
                    "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com",
                    "spot.amazonaws.com",
                    "spotfleet.amazonaws.com",
                    "transitgateway.amazonaws.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": "ec2:*",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEqualsIgnoreCase": {
                "ec2:ImageID": "ami-002070d43b0a4f171"
            },
            "ForAnyValue:StringLike": {
                "ec2:Attribute/Condition": [
                    "Linux/Unix",
                    "CentOS*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Then the second policy I created denies marketplace instances from being launched except ones that I own or from Amazon:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "DenyMarketPlaceAMIAccess",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RunScheduledInstances",
            "ec2:RunInstances"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/ami-*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "ec2:Owner": [
                    "amazon",
                    "self"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Once these two policies are created I scoped these two policies as well as the two native policies to allow other EC2 instances from being launched.

1. AmazonEC2FullAccess
2. AWSCloudShellFullAccess
3. Custom policy 1
4. Custom policy 2

Example:

[image: Example-deny-centos]